# Series expansion of square root function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, taylor-expansion, radicals

Could I please know how to expand:

$$\sqrt{4-3x^2}$$

I simplified it to $\sqrt{1-\frac34x^2}$ but the question is if I let $x = x^2$, what will the coefficient of, say $x^5$ or $x^{10}$ be in the expansion?

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT :**

Rewrite
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4-3x^2}&=(4-3x^2)^\frac12\\
&=\left(4\left(1-\frac34x^2\right)\right)^\frac12\\
&=2\left(1-\frac34x^2\right)^\frac12\\
&=2\left(1-\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x\right)^2\right)^\frac12\\
\end{align}
Now, let $y=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}x$ and use binomial series for [$\left(1-y^2\right)^\frac12$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#History).

Comment: thanks but how do I interpret the coefficients of the expansion with all this changing of variables?

Comment: also wouldn't it be easier to use the taylor series expansion instead?

Comment: @JqueryNinja Have you clicked the given link? In the given link, first you use $y$ to the binomial series. After that, substitute $y=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x$. The rest, should be easy.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey : Why I hate your equation-only link : right-clicking on it does not permit opening in a new tab or new window.  Additionally, the link is to a page about binomial series, so the matching semantics come from the phrase "binomial series for [equation]".